# Fill ViewModel with Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I created this `Stored Procedure` in Sql Server:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_GetUsrsofRole] (@RoleId int)
AS
;WITH CTE_UsersInRole AS
(
    SELECT 
     U.Id AS [UserId], U.Name AS [UserName] , U.Family AS [UserFamily] , R.Id AS[RoleID],R.Name AS [RoleName]
    FROM AspNetUserRoles AU 
    INNER JOIN AspNetRoles R ON R.Id=AU.RoleId
    INNER JOIN AspNetUsers U ON U.ID=AU.UserId
)
SELECT
     C.RoleID,C.RoleName,C.UserFamily,C.UserId,C.UserName
FROM CTE_UsersInRole C
    WHERE C.RoleID=@RoleId
GO
```

and this is my View Model:

```
public class UserInRoleVM
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string UserFamily { get; set; }
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }

}
```

now I need to fill the View Model with this code in asp Core:

```
public IEnumerable<UserInRoleVM> GetUserOfRole(int id)
{
    List<UserInRoleVM> users = new List<UserInRoleVM>();
    users = TableAsNoTracking.FromSql("EXEC usp_GetUsrsofRole @p0", id).ToList();
    return users;
}
```

but it gives me this error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List'
>   to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List' FisziShimi.Services E:\MyProject\Farshid\Backend\FisziShimi\FisziShimi.Services\Services\UserRoleService.cs 26  Active

How can I solve this problem?

**Update:**

```
 public DbSet<TEntity> Entities { get; }
 public virtual IQueryable<TEntity> Table => Entities;
 public virtual IQueryable<TEntity> TableAsNoTracking => Entities.AsNoTracking();
```

Comment: @CodeNotFound yes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do something like the following. Using your context and the model representing your view model you can pull from a stored procedure like so.

```
List<UserInRoleVM> users = new List<UserInRoleVM>();
using (var context = new DataContext())
{
   SqlParameter Parameter = new SqlParameter("@p0", code);
   users = context.Database.SqlQuery<UserInRoleVM>("exec usp_GetUsrsofRole  @p0", Parameter).ToList();
}
return users;
```

Not sure if it matters but in your stored procedure its RoleID and in your model its RoleId. Not sure if it makes a difference or not.